# What code editor should I use for Python for Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, code-editor

I need a code editor for Python for Windows. I want something easy to install and i like it if the words are colorful :D

Comment: We all like colourful words! Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) question.

Comment: this question will get closed as it is off-topic, but - I personally use [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Sublime text 2 you will like it - http://www.sublimetext.com/2

also as SwankSwashbucklers said notepad++ is really good too, I've used it for years

Answer (score 1):

Try notepad++, it's easy to work with and colors python.
Here's a link: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/